# Why is the information rate of an error-correcting code defined by $\frac{\log_q\left(|\mathcal{C}|\right)}{n}$?

Tags: coding-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an error-correcting code of length $n$ and $q$ the number of distinct symbols of the alphabet. We define the information rate of $\mathcal{C}$ by
$$\frac{\log_q\left(|\mathcal{C}|\right)}{n}.$$
I know it generalizes the concept which is connected to the time needed for the transmission of information, but why is it defined like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $|\cal C|$ different codewords, each of length $n.$ The number of $q-$ary strings of length $\ell$ is $q^\ell,$ and therefore, you need the smallest length $\ell$ which satisfies
$$
q^{\ell} \geq |\cal C|,
$$
in order to represent the different message words, each one corresponding to a unique codeword. Take logs to base $q$ (strictly speaking there should be a ceiling function on $\log(|\cal C|)$ but let's ignore this) to get
$$
\ell = \log_q(|\cal C|).
$$
The transmitted codewords are length $n,$ so the *ratio* of the information bearing symbols to the total number of symbols transmitted is the rate of the code:
$$
\frac{\log_q(|\cal C|)}{n}.
$$

**Edit:** So, if you have a message $\ell$ symbols long, you can define the parity symbols as the remaining $n-\ell$ symbols by means of some set of equations (usually but not always linear). See, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction)

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me what the intuitive idea of this definition is? How should I interpret it? Is it the proportion of well-decoded positions in the code? That's my real problem, frankly.

Comment: It's the proportion of information bearing symbols, the rest are "parity/check" symbols, once you decode all the symbols, the message is restricted to the information bearing symbols. The decoding works by recovering all the symbols in the codeword, that's why parity symbols are needed, to correct errors.

Comment: I have to investigate a little more what the parity symbols are… I imagine it refers to those that belong to the alphabet but are not in the codeword, but I really doubt that. To not bother you anymore, could you provide me with something to understand it better or investigate about it?